# How can I get the generic type of a parameterized generic used to annotate a dataclass property?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a dataclass:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    first: dict[str, int]
```

How can I determine that the generic type `dict` is the type expected with a `str` to `int` mapping? I want to be able to do something like:

```
for field in dataclasses.fields(Foo):
    if generic_type_of_field == dict:
        <<do something specific to this field needing to be a dict>>
    elif generic_type_of_field == list:
        <<do something specific to this field needing to be a list>>
```

I have tried using `dataclasses.fields(Foo)` to get the fields, then taking `field.type`. This just gives me `dict[str, int]` which is a `<class 'types.GenericAlias'>` type. Is there something more I can do here?

I can get the paramaterizations of the `dict` generic via `get_args(field.type)` which gives me `(<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>)` (which I do need) but I don't have run out of knowledge on even searching on the topic now so I am asking here.

Comment: You mean validate the `first` attribute of a `Foo` instance _at runtime_? The type annotations are generally used for _static_ analysis of type safety.

Comment: I want to do a static analysis on the class `Foo`. I want to take the dataclass and convert it to a schema for a 3rd party library which doesn't accept `list` or `dict` as valid types. So as an example, I want to be able to take `list[str]` from the dataclass and have it be `Array(str)` on the converted schema (`Array` being the 3rd party lib type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to tell the *original* generic type of a specified generic type, you can use [`typing.get_origin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin).

The problem is that it will return `None`, if you pass it a non-specified generic type. If you want to account for that, the simplest solution I can think of something along these lines:

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import get_origin


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    first: dict[str, int]
    second: dict
    third: list[float]


def generic_base(t: type) -> type:
    origin = get_origin(t)
    if origin is not None:
        return origin
    return t


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for field in dataclasses.fields(Foo):
        if generic_base(field.type) is dict:
            print(field.name, "is a dict")
        elif generic_base(field.type) is list:
            print(field.name, "is a list")
```

The output:

```
first is a dict
second is a dict
third is a list
```

Comment: @MartinOLeary Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem to your satisfaction, feel free to mark it as accepted.